# How to get a CAEmitterLayer from Canvas

Tags: ios, c4, caemitterlayer

I am trying to follow the tutorial about iOS particle systems here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/6063/uikit-particle-systems-in-ios-5-tutorial

I am having trouble casting the `self.canvas.layer` in C4Workspace.m to a `CAEmitterLayer`. The code compiles just fine but fails at runtime.

I tried this:

```
    particlesystem = (CAEmitterLayer *)self.canvas.layer;
```

But I receive this error every time.

```
-[C4Layer setEmitterPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa183830
```

It seems that I am not casting or exposing methods properly. How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply cast one layer as another.  In order for a view to have a non-standard layer, you need to subclass it and define the `+layerClass` method:

```
@implementation MyViewSubclass

+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEmitterLayer class];
}

...
```

Unfortunately for your case, the view you're working with has already set up a custom layer, [`C4Layer`, which can be seen on GitHub](https://github.com/C4Framework/C4iOS/blob/master/C4iOS/implementation/C4Layer.m).  This layer is doing a lot and you don't want to try replacing it.

What you can do is insert your own sublayer into your canvas:

```
CAEmitterLayer *myLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
myLayer.frame = self.canvas.bounds;
[self.canvas.layer addSublayer:myLayer];
```

This emitter layer will now overlay your layer and you can add any effects you want.  If you want the emitter below other layers, you can use `insertSublayer:myLayer atIndex:0`.